Parallel requests and report
Simple task:
@task
    def get_test(self):
        def func_query(url: str):
            with self.client.get(url) 
        group = Group()
        for url in url_list:
            group.spawn(func_query, url)
        group.join()

Suppose, url_list have 15 items
If I run this task ONCE, I will see 15 requests and 15 rps in the statistics
How can I make ONE pool launch appear in the statistics as ONE request?

You can log a separate ”request” in addition to the ones you made, using measure. Something like
  self.environment.events.request.measure("myrequestType", "myRequestName") as request_meta:
      for url in url_list:
          group.spawn(func_query, url)
      group.join()

You can use your own requests.Session instead of the one provided by HttpUser/self.client) to avoid logging individual requests.
